# Laravel chunk filter collection

Tags: laravel

Actually i have a simple collection but i need to make a filter to this collection and the filter call GoogleMaps to determine the distance between origin and destination, the problem is that i have more than 100 row $arbitres and this part of the process is getting very very very long.

How could i do to get more performance ?

I would like to try chunk but a get

> Method newQuery does not exist.

`

here my method to get the collection :

```
   $arbitres = Licencies::getArbitres($rencontre->dt_rencontre);

public static function getArbitres($date){


        $licences = Licencies::whereIn('activite_licencie_id' , [24,25,50,80])
            ->where('valid_licence_id' , 3)
            ->where('saison_id' , self::getSaison()->id)
            ->where('dispo' , 1)
            ->whereHas('fonctions')
            ->whereHas('divisions')
            ->whereDoesntHave('rencontreOfficiels', function ($query) use ($date) {
                $query->where('dt_rencontre', $date);
            })->get();

        return $licences;
    }
```

here my process who is getting so long : ('m doing this in order to filter $arbitres with the shortest distance.

```
for($i=0; $i <= 1200 ; $i+=200){

                        $geo_filter = $arbitres->filter(function ($arbitre) use ($rencontre , $i) {

                            $origin = $arbitre->lb_adresse .' '. $arbitre->lb_ville_naissance .' '. $arbitre->cd_dept_naissance;
                            $destination = $rencontre->stade->adresse_stade .' '. $rencontre->stade->ville_stade .' '. $rencontre->stade->cd_post_stade;

                            $distance = getDistance($origin, $destination);
                            $distance = (float)$distance;

                            if($distance <= $i){
                                return true;
                            }

                            return false;
                        });


                        if ($geo_filter->isNotEmpty()) {
                            $arbitres = $geo_filter;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
```

fonction getdistance :

```
 function getDistance($origin, $destination){

        $distance = 0;

        $response = \GoogleMaps::load('directions')
            ->setParam([
                'origin'          => $origin,
                'destination'     => $destination,
                'mode' => 'driving' ,
                'language' => 'fr',

            ])->get();

        $parsed_json = (json_decode($response));

        if($parsed_json->status != "NOT_FOUND") {
            $result = $parsed_json->{'routes'}[0]->{'legs'}[0]->{'distance'}->{'text'};
            $a = $result;
            $b = str_replace(" km",'',$a);
            $distance = str_replace(",",'.',$b);
        }

        if(is_numeric($distance)){
            $distance = $distance * 2;
        }


        return $distance;
    }
```

Comment: I wouldn't think that calling an external API at runtime for 100+ requests is a good option. Could you use linear distance instead of the driving distance?

Comment: what do you mean by linear distance, linear distance from the api ? yes i agree to really not good

Comment: It looks like you're calculating the driving distance between two points. Could you use the real linear (straight point-to-point) distance instead? If yes, that opens up other options that are far more scaleable.

Comment: between two addresses :(

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: I get two address like zip code city ect ... not to points latitude and longitude! It’s a problem I guess no ?

Comment: Why can't you just geolocate the addresses when you add them to your database, then geolocate the single origin point at runtime, and using math, calculate the linear distance between then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208084/discussion-between-mathieu-mourareau-and-fubar).